# Как задать параметру line-height значение высоты блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass, scss

Необходимо расположить текст по центру блока (текст в одну строку). Решил использовать `line-height` равный высоте блока, но высота блока помимо того что она имеет дефолтное значение, еще и динамическая. Подскажите, как можно вставить высоту блока в параметр `line-height`? Возможно, для этого есть какие-то функции или миксины для sass?

Comment: Вопрос, скорее, должен называться "Как расположить текст по вертикальному центру блока?". Line-height тут ни при чем.

Comment: @labris, нормальный заголовок у него. Заголовки разные нужны.

Comment: @labris Есть масса способов достигнуть этой цели (падингами, абсолютным позиционированием и т.д.) но я выбрал для себя этот и поставил четкий вопрос, поэтому не вижу смысла в вашем замечании.

Comment: Это как "вам шашечки или ехать?" Нужно решение или нужен line-height?

Comment: @labris Хотите считать свое мнение верным? - считайте, но зачем навязывать его другим.

Answer (score 3):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

Comment: Это самый правильный способ. :)
Такой же вопрос обсуждался тут - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686065/set-line-height-as-a-percentage-relative-to-the-parent-element ; разные способы решения - https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}
div:nth-of-type(2){
    height: 100px;
}
div:nth-of-type(3){
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>text-middle</div>
<div>text-middle</div>
<div>text-middle</div>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Хотя насчёт рациональности не уверен :)

Comment: Flex это конечно хорошо, но если бы я его использовал то не задумывался над этим вопросом.